# How to join Firebase and BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I'm trying to analyze an app user data now have access to the Firebase and Google BigQuery data. To do some analysis, I need to link these two database together by identify the users. In the database of Firebase, I have a field named user and I hope I could find a field in the BigQuery database which contains the same information to link these two database. But I only find a field named app instance id in BigQuery, which is not the same as user field in Firebase and I don't know how to join these two data source by a common field. Is anyone can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not automatically record User identification in its Analytics data. If you want that, you should set the relevant value yourself in by calling [`setUserId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setUserId(java.lang.String)).